How to pin header to the top using compositional layout?

How to pin header to the top using compositional layout? I know about pinToVisibleBounds. But how can I pin header for whole scroll, not only for one section? I tried to use pinToVisibleBounds, but it hides when I scroll other sections.

i have same issue too
did u find it?
